# Application crashes when dynamically storing string and apply it to the listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I am stroing bunch of comments in a String Array because i want to use that string array with ListView but i don't know why my application crashes...

For Example if i use the following string Array it doesn't crashes:

```
String[] values = new String[] { "value1",
                 "value2",
                 "value3",
                 "value4" };
```

But when i try to dynamically add data for

```
String[] Comments=new String[20];
```

It shows an error...

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            super.onPostExecute(result);

            JSONObject jsonObject;
            try {
                jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
                for (int i = 1; i <= jsonObject.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject jsonInnerObject = jsonObject
                            .getJSONObject(Integer.toString(i));

                    Comment = jsonInnerObject.getString("comment_text");
                    Comment_owner = jsonInnerObject.getString("comment_owner");

                    Comments[i] = Comment;

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }


                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(showStatus.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1,
                    Comments);

            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
```

my json data is:

```
{
    "1": {
        "comment_text": "its k...",
        "comment_owner": "hello"
    },
    "2": {
        "comment_text": "hello",
        "comment_owner": "hello"
    },
    "3": {
        "comment_text": "hmmmm....",
        "comment_owner": "hello"
    },
    "4": {
        "comment_text": "really...?",
        "comment_owner": "hello"
    }
}
```

log cat

```
05-26 23:45:31.807: E/AndroidRuntime(16334): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-26 23:45:31.807: E/AndroidRuntime(16334): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-26 23:45:31.807: E/AndroidRuntime(16334):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:394)
05-26 23:45:31.807: E/AndroidRuntime(16334):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
05-26 23:45:31.807: E/AndroidRuntime(16334):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2340)
05-26 23:45:31.807: E/AndroidRuntime(16334):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1793)
05-26 23:45:31.807: E/AndroidRuntime(16334):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:678)
05-26 23:45:31.807: E/AndroidRuntime(16334):    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:739)
05-26 23:45:31.807: E/AndroidRuntime(16334):    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1638)
05-26 23:45:31.807: E/AndroidRuntime(16334):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2170)
05-26 23:45:31.807: E/AndroidRuntime(16334):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13846)
05-26 23:45:31.807: E/AndroidRuntime(16334):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4466)
05-26 23:45:31.807: E/AndroidRuntime(16334):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:948)
05-26 23:45:31.807: E/AndroidRuntime(16334):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13846)
05-26 23:45:31.807: E/AndroidRuntime(16334):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4466)
05-26 23:45:31.807: E/AndroidRuntime(16334):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
05-26 23:45:31.807: E/AndroidRuntime(16334):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13846)
05-26 23:45:31.807: E/AndroidRuntime(16334):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4466)
05-26 23:45:31.807: E/AndroidRuntime(16334):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1649)
05-26 23:45:31.807: E/AndroidRuntime(16334):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1507)
05-26 23:45:31.807: E/AndroidRuntime(16334):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1420)
05-26 23:45:31.807: E/AndroidRuntime(16334):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13846)
05-26 23:45:31.807: E/AndroidRuntime(16334):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4466)
05-26 23:45:31.807: E/AndroidRuntime(16334):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
05-26 23:45:31.807: E/AndroidRuntime(16334):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13846)
05-26 23:45:31.807: E/AndroidRuntime(16334):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4466)
05-26 23:45:31.807: E/AndroidRuntime(16334):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2168)
05-26 23:45:31.807: E/AndroidRuntime(16334):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1926)
05-26 23:45:31.807: E/AndroidRuntime(16334):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1140)
05-26 23:45:31.807: E/AndroidRuntime(16334):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4726)
05-26 23:45:31.807: E/AndroidRuntime(16334):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:747)
05-26 23:45:31.807: E/AndroidRuntime(16334):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:567)
05-26 23:45:31.807: E/AndroidRuntime(16334):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:536)
05-26 23:45:31.807: E/AndroidRuntime(16334):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:733)
05-26 23:45:31.807: E/AndroidRuntime(16334):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
05-26 23:45:31.807: E/AndroidRuntime(16334):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-26 23:45:31.807: E/AndroidRuntime(16334):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
05-26 23:45:31.807: E/AndroidRuntime(16334):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5000)
05-26 23:45:31.807: E/AndroidRuntime(16334):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-26 23:45:31.807: E/AndroidRuntime(16334):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-26 23:45:31.807: E/AndroidRuntime(16334):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
05-26 23:45:31.807: E/AndroidRuntime(16334):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
05-26 23:45:31.807: E/AndroidRuntime(16334):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: post the relevant stacktrace pls

Comment: Also, if you have the JSON, or a sample of the structure, that would help too

Comment: @Raghunandan hope it would help..

Comment: @shabeer : We still need the logcat showing the stacktrace

Comment: @shabeer still no stacktrace

Comment: @Blaine hope it would help..

Comment: is this the complete StackTrace?

Comment: @Raghunandan look at it now

Comment: @PedroTeran yes it is..

Comment: @Squonk look at it now

Comment: @shabeer is `Comments` populated with items??

Comment: @shabeer instead of array use a arraylist. add items to the list and replace Comment in arrayadapter with list. The adapter looks alright

Comment: @shabeer check the answer now it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are better off using a `ArrayList` instead of a `Array` as list is dynamic.

```
ArrayList<String> list = ArrayList<String>();
JSONObject jsonObject;
        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
            for (int i = 1; i <= jsonObject.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject jsonInnerObject = jsonObject
                        .getJSONObject(Integer.toString(i));

                Comment = jsonInnerObject.getString("comment_text");
                Comment_owner = jsonInnerObject.getString("comment_owner");
                list.add(Comment);

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }


 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(showStatus.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1,
                list);

 listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Also follow java naming conventions. You have variables that start with caps